# Pythonic way for a conditional return in a function

Tags: python, return

I have a couple of functions that return either a number or `None`. I want my wrapper function to return the first result that is not `None`. Is there any other way to do this than as following?

```py
def func1():
    return None
def func2():
    return 3
def func3():
    return None

def wrapper():
    result = func1()
    if result is not None:
        return result
    result = func2()
    if result is not None:
        return result
    result = func3()
    if result is not None:
        return result
```

I am aware of `return func1() or alternative`; which returns the outcome of `func1()` unless it is `None`, then `alternative` is returned. In the most optimal situation I do something like (pseudo code):

```py
return func1() or continue
return func2() or continue
return func3() or continue
```

Comment: What about `return func1() or func2() or func3()` ?

Comment: Hmm I like that better already! What if there's fifty functions though?

Comment: @jorijnsmit: In that case you would have a real loop iterating over a list of functions, with a single break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a loop which will return the first non-`None` value it finds.

```
def wrapper():
    for f in [func1, func2, func3]:
        result = f()
        if result is not None:
            return result
```

If every function returns `None`, `wrapper` will as well by reaching the end of the body without an explicit `return`.

Shortened slightly in Python 3.8 or later,

```
def wrapper():
    for f in [func1, func2, func3]:
        if (result := f()) is not None:
            return result
```

You can also make use of the `any` function:

```
def wrapper():
    if any((result := f()) is not None for f in [func1, func2, func3]):
        return result
```

(I prefer the explicit loop; YMMV.)

Answer (score 2):

If there's only three functions, and you don't care about distinguishing None from other falsey values, you can use

```
return func1() or func2() or func3()
```

If there are lots of functions, or if you want to be more discriminating about the return values, then you could put them all in a list and use

```
return next(x for x in (f() for f in funcs) if x is not None)
```

If you want to cope with all of your functions returning None, you can add a default value for next, e.g.

```
return next((x for x in (f() for f in funcs) if x is not None), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine map, filter and next:

```
def func1():
    print("executed func1()")
    return None
def func2():
    print("executed func2()")
    return 3
def func3():
    print("executed func3()")
    return None

functions = (func1,func2,func3)
call      = lambda f:f()
result    = next(filter(None,map(call,functions)),None)

print("result:",result)
```

output:

```
executed func1()
executed func2()
result 3
```

*func 3 is not executed*

If your functions have parameters you can still use this approach by building the list of functions with lambdas:

```
def func1(p1):
    print(f"executed func1({p1})")
    return None
def func2(p2a,p2b):
    print(f"executed func2{(p2a,p2b)}")
    return 3
def func3(p3):
    print(f"executed func3({p3})")
    return None

functions = [
               lambda: func1(10),
               lambda: func2("X",99),
               lambda: func3(3.5)
            ]
call      = lambda f:f()
result    = next(filter(None,map(call,functions)),None)

print(result)
```

output:

```
executed func1(10)
executed func2('X', 99)
3
```

Comment: Thanks for that `lambda` construction, that's really useful to be able to pass different arguments!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def wrapper():
    functions = [func1, func2, func3]
    return next(filter(lambda result: result is not None,
                       f() for f in functions),
                None)
```

It returns `None` if all the functions return `None`.